# how to get java app full path in windows

Tags: java, windows

1.I already tried by wmic process get name,executablepath,processid|findstr pid. but the result is the path of java.exe rather than i expected.i want to get the java app's full path like test.jar's full path.    xx.bat:

```
    %~d0
    cd %~dp0 
    java -jar test.jar
```

2.java code:

```
    String path = "..../xx.bat"; 
    String cmd = "cmd /c start " + path.replaceAll(" ", "\" \""); 
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

3.the question is: how can i get the java app named test full path.

Comment: You have to remember, your `test.jar` is been executed by `java.exe`, so it's been passed to `java.exe` as a parameter.  You could try using `System.getProperty("user.dir")` which will return the "working" directory, which based on your command line, should return the path the jar file is been executed within

Comment: im sure the test.jar is been executed,because i can get the `pid` of test.jar in java code. so i want get the test.jar full path by pid.

Comment: Yes, it's been executed, by `java.exe`, the Jar file itself is not executable, from a OS point of view

Comment: my point is that i just want a java app's full path of each java.exe in windows,which java app is running in windows. so the answer need system commands in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of the .class file for the currently executing class is given by

```
this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

Comment: thank for your answer,however,i need to get the java app's full  path which already is running ,actually , want the way to get path in another java app.

Comment: @star Then I suggest you say so in your question.